# Как автоматически сворачивать namespace в VS 2022?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Можно ли где-то в Visual Studio 2022 включить автоматическое сворачивание namespace'ов из

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    class MyClass {}
}
```

В

```
namespace MyApplication;

class MyClass {}
```

Comment: Ставим курсор на строку с неймспейсом, вызываем меню Quick Actions: кликаем мышкой на лампочку слева или шорткат жмём (`Ctrl+.`, `Alt+Enter`). Там будет пункт Convert to file-scoped namespace.

Comment: Можно просто ; поставить, но вопрос в удобстве, каждый раз это делать - не очень, хотелось бы, чтобы файлы сразу такие создавались :(

Comment: Это делается через стили кода, либо проекта, либо самой студии. Обычно, если у проекта свой набор стилей, то лучше сделать `.editconfig` файл, и прописать это там. Ну а так, настройки студии - Текстовый редактор - C# - Стиль кода - Общее - Объявления пространства имен = Область видимого файла

Comment: По идее, это можно делать с помощью Code cleanup. Но у меня он не работает.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, то что нужно, спасибо, можете оформить как ответ

Comment: Можете написать его самостоятельно, а я пожалуй откажусь)

Answer (score 0):

Ответ в комментариях от [EvgeniyZ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220553/evgeniyz): Средства - Параметры - Текстовый редактор - C# - Стиль кода - Общее - Объявления пространства имен = Область видимого файла
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]